# Can't updatet a many to many relationship

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have 3 classes with many to many constraint in spring, the problem is when i try to update an existing user with a role I get: "field active hasn't a default value" but in the debug I can see everything.
I also tried to add all the Fetch.Type Eager but the problem in that when i Fetch them i get infinite roles and privileggi values in the json:
(I'll cut some attributes from that)

```
public class Utente{
@JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "utente_ruolo",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "utente_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    private Set<Ruoli> roles;
}

public class Ruoli{
  @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Set<Utente> utenti;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "ruolo_privileggi",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "priv_id",referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    private Set<Privileggi> privileggi;
}

public class Privileggi{
  @Column(name = "active", nullable = false)
    private Boolean active;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "privileggi", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Ruoli> ruoli;
}
```

The method i using to add a role to a user is this:

```
public Utente addRolesToUser(List<RuoliDTO> ruoliDTO, String username) {
        StringBuilder noPresentedRoles = new StringBuilder(" ");
        Set<Ruoli> roles = new HashSet<>();
        for (RuoliDTO ruoloDTO : ruoliDTO) {
            Optional<Ruoli> ruolo = ruoliRepository.findByRoleName(ruoloDTO.getRoleName());
            ruolo.ifPresentOrElse(
                    roles::add,
                    () -> noPresentedRoles.append(ruoloDTO.getRoleName())
            );
        }

        if (noPresentedRoles.length() > 1) {
            log.error("These roles are not present in the db: {}", noPresentedRoles);
        }

        log.info("{}.addRolesToUser adding user: {} to list roles: {}", this.getClass().getName(), username, roles.size());
        Utente utente = utenteRepository.findByUsername(username).orElseThrow(() ->
                new CustomException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, USER_NOTFOUND,
                        String.format("the username: %s was not found in the db", username))
        );

        utente.getRoles().addAll(roles);
        return utenteRepository.save(utente);
    }
```